# Clear data structures/Restart Application in Android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have a menu button called "Restart" which restarts a simple text game I have on the screen using ArrayLists. I'm not sure exactly how to "restart" my application so if the user wants to play a new game I can create new random variables for them and clear the screen.

The optimal code would be something that would just let me restart the application when "restart" is hit on the menu.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your activity to draw the views solely on the array list instance variables.
2. It checks for variables `onResume` too.
3. Create a restart method that deploys the changes in the variable.
   with prototype

   ```
   public void restart(View v) {
       //your arraylist initialization here.
       // Call the following method on your top view.
       YourTopView.invalidate();
   }
   ```
4. In the button declaration in the layout file `android:onClick="restart"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case to use [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

Basically when a stage started, you store the data structure to Originator and when you want to restart, you just get the previous memento saved and restore the current data structure based on the memento retrieved.

From [SimplyVinay.com](http://www.simplyvinay.com/Post/40/Design-Patterns-for-Dummies.-The-Memento-Pattern.aspx) :

> The memento pattern deals with capturing an object’s internal state and saving it externally so that the internal state of that object can be restored later. This pattern is usually used in computer games where the state of the game can be saved, and can be started from the same point.